# Error with map & flatMap on RDDs in Eclipse with Spark

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark

I finally have Eclipse set up to be able to use Spark in a worksheet. I have the Scala 2.10.5 library in my build path & also included this jar: spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar

I can do most things on RDDs except map and flatMap. For example, given this data (sampleData.txt):

```
0,1 0 0
0,2 0 0
1,0 1 0
1,0 2 0
2,0 0 1
2,0 0 2
```

The following code gives a "macro has not been expanded" error.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD._

object sparkTestWS {
  val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("My App")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  // start model section
  val data = sc.textFile("sampleData.txt")
  val dataM = data.map(x => x)
}
```

I looked up this macro error, and there's a post saying that it has to do with implicit Types and that it will be (or now is) fixed with Scala 2.11, but Spark is on Scala 2.10...

I also wondered if I might need to explicitly import the classes with these functions since there was a post that said that some implicit imports need to be made explicit, but so far I haven't been able to figure out what to import. I've tried scala.Array, scala.immutable.*, org.apache.spark.rdd.*, etc.

Any ideas? There are other posts stating that people are using Spark with Eclipse, so there must be a way to make Spark work in Eclipse (though the posts don't note whether or not they are using Scala worksheets.) I'm pretty new to Spark and only slightly less new to Scala, so any advice would be greatly appreciated. I really like Scala worksheets, so I'd like to get all this working if possible. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good to me.

Your problem is likely to be with the worksheets themselves. They are nice but being based on the REPL they are not exactly the same as compiled classes, they do a bunch of extra things in order to allow the code to flow (like redefining the same variable), each REPL command is wrapped on it own scope and this can mess with implicits, imports, etc. in subtle ways.

If you are new to both Scala and Spark, I would recommend using compiled classes for the time being and postpone Worksheets until you get a better grasp of the fundamentals.

That said, have you tried [spark-shell](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#interactive-analysis-with-the-spark-shell)?

Comment: Ok bummer. Yup, I started with spark-shell (start simple!) and then thought it would be nice to work in eclipse. I'll wait and see if anyone else has figured out the worksheets plus Spark combo, but thanks for your response!

Comment: I use Intellij myself. One comment though: the benefit of worksheets would probably minimal. Spark does lazy evaluation of data and most of that remotely, so I see no much of an advantage over just having a main class and then run it, you will not see the data cleanly printed at the side, just a bunch of types.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I haven't tried Intellij yet, but I should probably take a look at it. The data will print out in the worksheet if you do a println or a take(). These & other functions work on the RDDs, but for some reason, it's just the map & flatMap that don't work. Isn't that odd? I'm trying to get the worksheet working because I tend to work interactively - I don't usually compile/run unless I have to (call me lazy.) I know it's weird to be so attached to the worksheets, but I am...